# Google Docs Gives a Strange Popup

Tags: google-docs

On a mac computer, when I press Option+Shift+C while on a google doc, I get a strange warning saying: "Are you sure you want to cancel your recording? You cannot get your video back after you do this." Does anyone know what this could be referring to?
[image]